# Crashing before the app starts

Tags: ios, swift, crash, exc-bad-instruction

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    let bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bgmusic", withExtension: "mp3")!
    backgroundMusicPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL)
    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()

    // Configure the view
    let skView:SKView = self.view as! SKView
    //skView.showsFPS = true
    //skView.showsNodeCount = true

    // Create and Configure the sciene
    let scene:SKScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
```

I'm getting

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

and it's crashing the app before it even starts. New to programming btw.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because your code isn't safe at all! In your first line you force unwrap a url that may or may not be able to be formed by the system, and then in the next line you force a try without catching any errors. I suspect, however, that the error is in your first line. The system can't find the music file you're trying to load, but you're force unwrapping it, which will cause it to crash.